# Check for consecutive characters in an excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

If you could help me I am in need to finding out if a character of the alphabet repeats consecutively 3 or more times in a cell, eg if a cell is "aronfff" or "aaaaaron" I want it to return true otherwise to return false eg "aaron".

```
Function InRowChars(cell As String) As Boolean
Dim repeats As Integer, char As String, i As Integer
repeats = 0
char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

For i = 1 To Len(cell)
    If cell.Value = " " Then
        repeats = chars + 1
    Else
        chars = 0
    End If
Next i

If chars = 3 Then
    InRowChars = True
Else
    InRowChars = False
End If

End Function
```

I don't know how to get the value of the cell to be checked against the alphabet.

Comment: It is indeed a bit difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Can you give a few examples? E.g., input and expected output?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry for being vague, so lets say I have a cell that contains the string "aronfff" or "aaaaaaron" i want the function to return true if it finds 3 consecutive repeated characters wherever may they be, like in the cases above or false if it doesn't - "aaron".

Comment: Cool, add it to the question, using edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a another regex solution that returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether or not there are three or more repeating alphabetic characters:

```
Option Explicit
Function TripleChars(S As String) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])\1\1"
    .ignorecase = True 'edit as desired
    TripleChars = .test(S)
End With
End Function
```

And here is an explanation of the Regex Pattern:

### ([a-z])\1\1

```
([a-z])\1\1
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `([a-z])`

  - [Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-z]`
- [Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`
- [Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Thank you its working :). I have one question though can I use these regex patterns in a combinatoric way? Let's say i want the pattern to be any 2 or more alphabetic characters used in a group (eg: "ab"/"abb"/"abbb"/), 2 or more times in a string(eg: "abab"/"ababab"/"abbabb"/"abbabbabb") if the idea is clear..

Comment: @CalinLencar  You would construct a regex that will capture the pattern you want to test and place that within the capturing group.  This is best done with a dedicated tool.  I use `RegexBuddy` but that is not free.  There are free testing tools available on the web.  Once you have the regex, adapting to VBA code is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with regular expressions. I've made a function example that also accept the number of minimum characters desired:

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Function ContainsConsecutiveChars(ByRef CellRef As Range, Optional ConsecutiveCount As Long = 3) As Boolean

  Dim chars() As String
  chars = Split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z", ",")

  With New RegExp
    .Pattern = Join(chars, "{" & ConsecutiveCount & ",}|")
    ContainsConsecutiveChars = .test(CellRef.Value2)
  End With

End Function
```

Comment: I like the Optional value idea:)

Answer (score 2):

I see you already have a RegEx answer now.  Just finished my version so thought I'd post it to.
@Thunderframe - I liked the optional bit, so have blatantly taken it for my version to.

```
Public Function RepeatingChars(Target As Range, Optional ConsecutiveCount As Long = 3) As Variant

    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(.)\1{" & ConsecutiveCount - 1 & ",}"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(Target.Value)
    If REMatches.Count = 0 Then
        RepeatingChars = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        RepeatingChars = REMatches(0)
    End If

End Function
```

The function will return duplicates of any character, or #NA if no matches found.

**Edit**
After a quick re-read of your question you can replace the whole `If...End If` block with `RepeatingChars = REMatches.Count <> 0` to return *TRUE/FALSE*.  Remember to change the return type of the function to `Boolean` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
Option Explicit

Function checkChars(inputCell As String, Optional repeat As Long = 3) As Boolean

    Dim cnt                 As Long
    Dim previous            As String
    Dim countResult         As Long

    For cnt = 1 To Len(inputCell)

        If previous = Mid(inputCell, cnt, 1) Then
            countResult = countResult + 1                
        Else
            countResult = 1
        End If

        If countResult = (repeat) Then
            checkChars = True
            Exit Function
        End If

        previous = Mid(inputCell, cnt, 1)
    Next cnt

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print checkChars("lalaaa")
    Debug.Print checkChars("lalaala", 2)
    Debug.Print checkChars("lalaala", 1)
    Debug.Print checkChars("lflalajajala", 2)

End Sub
```

The idea is that you can also pass the repeat number as an optional value, if it is different than 3. This is what you get as an output from the example:

```
True
True
True
False
```